# EntityFramework relationship management OnModelCreating()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, relationship, ef-core-6.0

I created the following entity:

```
public record Client
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [NotEmptyList(ErrorMessage = "At least 1 client scope is required")]
        public List<Scope> Scopes { get; set; }
    }
```

And the `Scope` class:

```
public record Scope
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And my DbContext looks like this:

```
public class ConfigurationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ConfigurationDbContext([NotNull] DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Scope> ApiScopes { get; set; }
}
```

When I do migration and update, my table 'ApiScopes' gets foreign key with name 'ClientId'. I don't have any idea how can I generate new ClientScopes table containing the foreign key to ApiScope and that ApiScope won't get a foreign key.

Comment: ApiScope is 1-to-many relationship with ClientScopes (1 ApiScope for many ClientScopes), right?

Comment: My code looks exactly like above. The "ClientScopes" table does not currently exist, but I want to do this instead of adding the foreign key "ClientId" to the "ApiScopes" table. I want a table 'ClientScopes' to be created containing the foreign key to an item from 'ApiScopes' table.

Comment: Could you please tell me why you want another table when you just one to many relationship?

Answer (score 0):

You can update Scope class:

```
public record Scope
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

You can edit ConfigurationDbContext:

```
public class ConfigurationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ConfigurationDbContext([NotNull] DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Scope>()
            .HasOne(s => s.Client)
            .WithMany(g => g.Scopes)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.ClientId);
    }

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Scope> ApiScopes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I didn't think about it. I tried to explain my thought further in the comment below the question.